# Even permutations, what is wrong?

Tags: permutations

Watch this following permutation in $S_8$ choose the even one's.

A.  (1 5 2 8 3 6)

B.  (1 5 4)(2 6)

C.  (3 8)(4 7 6)

D.  (1 8 4)(3 7 5 6)

E.  (1 8 5 4 6 3 2)

F.  (1 7)(3 4 5)(6 8)

---

even*even = even

even*odd = odd

odd*odd=even

in their cycle?

So I think that

a) even

b) odd*even = odd

c) even*odd = odd

d) odd*even = odd

e) even

f) odd*odd*even = even

So therefore A E F is the right answer. And that's not correct.

Help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: $(1\:5\:2\:8\:3\:6)=(1\:6)(1\:3)(1\:8)(1\:2)(1\:5)$ so its odd.

Comment: So my reasoning for thinking in multiplication does not matter?

Comment: Parity (thought of as $0$ or $1$ mod $2$) is additive, not multiplicative.  E.g., odd *plus* odd is even, while odd *times* odd is odd.

Comment: No that is incorrect. For easy remembrance "A permutation with n(even) splits into odd number of cycles of length 2 and a permutation with n(odd) splits into even number of cycles of length 2. " To count you add the number of cycles not multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

**Fact 1:**
A single cycle of length $n$ is odd when the length $n$ is even (!) and even when $n$ is odd.

**Fact 2:**
In a product we can multiply the parities (as in the integers) using the rule $-1$ is odd, and $1$ is even.

A) is a cycle of length 6, so it's odd.

B) is even $(1 3 2)$ times odd $(2 6)$, so odd.

C) is similarly odd.

D) is similarly odd (two disjoint cycles of length of different parity)

E) is even as it's one cycle whose length is $7$.

F) is odd times even times odd, so $(-1) \times 1 \times (-1) = 1$, so even.

So I only get E and F as even.